# How to solve AJAX Access-Control-Allow-Origin when posting between subdomains

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to solve a Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue that occurs when a user accesses my site via `http://domain.com`, and posts an ajax request to `http://www.domain.com`.

I assume the easiest way would be to rewrite all requests from `http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com`? If so, how would I go about enabling this?

Is there an alternate way to allow CORS requests like this?

***Example code below***

```
$(document).on('submit', "#registerform, #confirmreset", function(event){
            //disable default click operation
            event.preventDefault();

            var action_url = $(this).attr("action");
            $('#lightbox').fadeIn(250);
            $('#lightbox-content-table').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-lg fa-spin'></i> &nbsp;processing...");
          //  console.log(action_url);
          var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
          //  console.log(postData);

          $.post(action_url,postData,function(data){

            console.log(data);
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

           // if(obj.status == "error"){
            $('#lightbox-content-table').html(obj.message)

          //   }
          if(obj.status == "success" && obj.message == "Success!")
          {
            window.location.replace(obj.redirect).delay(0);
          }
        });

        });
```

Comment: the `www.` is not a different part/dir, but just an alias for the domain with `www`?

Comment: Rewrite the backend to parse the `Origin` request header and return the right `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: @RobW Thanks, so in the above edit would I be parsing `action_url`?

Comment: @alias51 No. You have to update your server-side code in the way I described in my previous comment. If you cannot control the server, then you're almost out of luck. If the web service supports JSONP, then you can use jQuery + JSONP. If not, and you really need the data, then you can use a [CORS Anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) to automatically get the right CORS headers on the resource (see https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere#documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to your sub domain simply add a response header for:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

if you use PHP it is like so:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

for ASP.Net you can simply try:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

without having access to your server and adding this header the only way is changing your browser setting which is not a real solution. for Google Chrome open it with a parameter like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

in firefox you have to change `about:config` like this:

```
about:config -> security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy -> false
```

Comment: `--disable-web-security` is a *really* big hammer, and non-portable.

Comment: sure it is, as I have said above it's not a real solution, besides this 2 way (modifying the server side for your subdomain and using the hammer) I'd offer to create a Handler if it is .Net based server, create a servlet if it is a Java based solution and for php simply create a php file which all do the same, giving you a full access to all other domains.

Comment: *(note that I'm not the OP)* There's another option: Use a CORS/JSONP proxy (see my comment on the question).

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` will grant permission to **every** site, not just yours. This will allow anyone to access any data that is protected by your users' credentials.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the easiest way would be to rewrite all requests from `http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com`? If so, how would I go about enabling this?

Assuming Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    # Your regular server config
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Which file would I put this in?

Comment: Also, doesn't this redirect www.example.com to example.com?

Comment: Your apache config (or a file loaded by it, I usually would use `/etc/apache/site-config/example.com.conf`. Yes, this redirects to `example.com`, you can swap them around if you'd rather go the other way.